# WordPress Reset password Strength set to medium

Tags: plugin-development, filters, woocommerce-offtopic, actions, password

I have been looking for an answer for a few days digging through hooks and actions.

I just cane seem to find a way to turn down the strength on the reset password page not sure if its through woo-commerce or WP

I have tried the following

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_min_password_strength', 'reduce_woocommerce_min_strength_requirement' );
    function reduce_woocommerce_min_strength_requirement( $strength ) {
    return 2;
}

add_filter( 'wc_password_strength_meter_params', 'reduce_strength_meter_settings' );
function reduce_strength_meter_settings( $data ) {

    return array_merge( $data, array(
        'min_password_strength' => 2,
        'i18n_password_hint' => 'Change Hint here'
    ) );

}
```

Comment: I have come to find that the site is using a plugin called Theme My Login (TML or tml) and thats were the forgot password stuff is coming from

Answer (score 0):

You'll find a discussion of how the password strength is computed here: [How is password strength calculated?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183061/how-is-password-strength-calculated) .

As an aside, there is some discussion (one is here: https://nakedsecurity.sophos.com/2015/03/02/why-you-cant-trust-password-strength-meters/ ) that password strength 'analyzers' don't really result in strong passwords.